# Does CSS "max-height" Only Work 1 Level Deep? How to Automatically Scroll Nested Web Layouts if so?

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive

I'm struggling with what seems should very much be a beginner task in CSS: **scrolling** and **heights** (when elements are nested more than 1 level deep).

I'd like to design layouts where default elements do not expand past their parent elements, and if they do, `overflow: auto` kicks in and they start scrolling.

I don't want to set `height; 100%` on every element though, as I need elements to only take up the space required, and so have been trying to use instead `max-height: 100%` or `max-height: inherit` on every element.

When using `height: 100%`, the height of the parent is correctly picked up even when elements are nested several layers deep, as seen here: [Code Pen 1](https://codepen.io/davidhmays/pen/QWOPxaP)

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 95vh;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.levelOne {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  /* Correctly gets parent height */
}

.levelTwo {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  /* Correctly gets grand-parent height */
}
```

```html
<div class="levelOne">
  <div class=levelTwo>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When attempting to not overflow a nested div with `max-height: 100%` however, it appears that the level 1 child correctly stops at the parent height, but a level 2 child will spill out. [Code Pen 2](https://codepen.io/davidhmays/pen/mdqgjyQ)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  max-height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 95vh;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.levelOne {
  background-color: blue;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* Correctly gets parent height*/
}

.levelTwo {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* DOESN'T get grandparent hight, but spills out of levelOne so overflow: auto never starts to scroll; */
}
```

```html
<div class="levelOne">
  <div class=levelTwo>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Why does `max-height: 100%` not top out at the grandparent's height, while `height: 100%' does? I would have expected similar behavior.
2. Is there a better method to not allow elements to spill out of their parent sizes?

I have also seen a recommendation to do something like the following, but if `max-hight` isn't able to calculate past the 1st layer deep, it fails too:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It seem like for some reason if the divs are a 1x1 css grid things work more consistently at deeper levels, but sometimes a grid is too much overhead, and I'm hoping to better understand the basics.

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't figure it out, but ```display: flex``` on layer 1 seems to fix it (even with more than two layers).

Comment: Ya I've noticed setting levelOne to display: flex or display: grid seems to allow max-height: 100% on levelTwo to correctly inherit the grandparent and parent height, but I don't understand why this is? Why does it fail for regular block elements - and only for max-height, while regular height does size levelTwo correctly?

My workaround as you mentioned is to wrap everything in a flex or grid, but that seems unnecessary. Is the browser somehow implementing the max-height specification incorrectly somehow?

Comment: max-height or height always need **height** as reference and never max-height or min-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need elements to only take up the space required

Setting widths relative to the parent will not make elements take up only the space required. By default `height` is set to `auto` which only makes elements as tall as they need to be.

> Stop levelTwo from overflowing levelOne & universally tell all elements to never expand beyond their parent

Decide what your children will do when they are too large to fit within their explicit height parent:

- Visibly overflow (Default)
- Hide (Bad practice)
- Scroll

> 1. Why does `max-height: 100%` not top out at the grandparent's height, while `height: 100%` does? I would have expected similar behavior.

> Why setting `height: 100%` on each works, but `max-height: 100%` does not

*MDN - The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as none.*

So because your levelOne container has a max-height and not a height, the max height is seen as 100% of auto - and 100% of "as much as you need" is a max-height of none.

> 2. Is there a better method to not allow elements to spill out of their parent sizes?

Please let me know if this example is in the direction you want.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 95vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.levelOne {
  background-color: blue;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* Correctly gets parent height*/
  overflow: auto;
}

.levelTwo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="levelOne">
  <div class=levelTwo>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

levelOne will be as big as it needs to be to fit it's content with default CSS height value of `auto`. It will cap out at `100%` of its parent height with the max height and scroll when the content exceeds this because of the `overflow: auto`.

Comment: Thanks, levelTwo though really is what I am trying to stop from overflowing though, so can't just move the overflow. The overflow is only an example to demonstrate that levelTwo is bigger than intended.

My real question then is how to stop levelTwo from overflowing levelOne, and why setting height:100% on each works, but max-height:100% does not, and how to universally tell all elements to never expand beyond their parent.

Comment: @DavidMays oh ok thank you for clarifying! I will try and answer that

Comment: @DavidMays Hopefully closer to answering your questions

Comment: Thanks! What's confusing me, is setting height:100% on both levelOne and levelTwo (not max-height) IS correctly limiting the levelTwo box size to no larger than level one.

It's only when using max-height on levelOne and levelTwo that levelTwo begins to spill out.

MDN says "The percentage is calculated with respect to height of the generated box's containing block."  Height does this correctly - levelOne with height:100% doesn't overflow, it's height is passed to level two having a height:100% and everything sizes correctly.

I don't understand why max-height behaves differently.

Comment: Also not sure why max-size:100% does work on levelTwo if levelOne is display: flex or display:grid, just not for display: block items.

Comment: @DavidMays I don't know why the CSSWG decided not to include max-height and min-height, maybe it broke backward-compatibility? You could probably pass down a custom property that you use for the height since you can't base off max-height.